# How to include the content of a CSS file into node EJS template

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using express and public folder for loading CSS inside a  tag. But I wonder if it is possible to load it as text directly on EJS template, similarly as including another EJS file. I know it is possible to load the css content using fs and sending it to the render function, but I wonder if EJS has a method for including any sort of file. Something similar to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <% include('../public/css/style.css') %>
</head>
<body>
    <% include('./partial.ejs') %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont think so. You could just include ejs files. Yet wondering whats the problem with **link tag**: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">`. Why would someone include a css or js file when we've got specific html tags to load em?!!! What's the use case?

Comment: @dNitro Lower G PageSpeed test rates

Comment: so i think TJ didn't notice that performance issue!!! ;) Template engines aren't meant to be used this way. As part of your build process you could always use task runners (like gulp) to replace your css links with their content (as well as uglify, minify, autoprefixfy and many other tasks). I am pretty sure such gulp task exists and you could easily find one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what advantage this approach has, but if you have custom objectives that require this behavior, you could just write the CSS in an EJS file.

```html
<!-- css/style.ejs -->
<style>
/* your CSS here... */
</style>
```

Then in your EJS file you can simply do

```html
<!-- in <head>... -->
<% include('./css/style.ejs') %>
```